# how to integrate a spring boot application into a legacy java application and isolate it?

Tags: java

we have a very old java web application (about 15 years old!) with servlet, Spring version 3 and ... technologies, I want to develop a rest API for this application, in order to be able to use modern technologies I decided to develop a new modern spring (boot) web application without an embedded server and bootstrap it using a new servlet that I will define in the legacy app `web.xml`. I also need to isolate dependencies using Java `ClassLoader`. it is obvious that the new app has dependencies inside the old one and I need to be able to inject them. I know this is possible (OSGI frameworks use a very similar approach). but I have some questions.

first question(s): is this a correct/sensible strategy for this task? is there any better way?

second question: where can I find some resources to study and learn in order to implement this strategy?

Comment: Is the new REST interface so strongly tied to the old application that it has to run as part of the same web app? If you package the REST interface (and it's dependencies) as a completely separate web app, you probably already have solved most of the problems.

Comment: YES. the REST interface will expose the service layer.

Comment: all the services are strongly tied together.

Comment: That is not an explanation why you can't split into two web apps. Unless you have specific reasons not to, and your question is far to generic and not detailed enough to guess what you are exactly doing, you could of course have the service layer running in both web apps.

Comment: you do not understand the problem. THE SERVICES ARE NOT COMPATIBLE WITH NEW LIBRARIES (LIKE SPRING). this is the whole point.

Comment: *where can I find some resources to study* - asking for external resources is off topic. Please edit and remove it from the question.\

Comment: I think in cases that one has no idea where to search for resources, it is valid to ask about these resources. I am not asking something like "where can I find some resources to learn java?!!".

Comment: There is absolutely no need to SHOUT with captials and act impatiently when someone is trying to help you. I have voted to close your question as it needs a lot more details about your exact situation for anyone to give reasonable advice. It probably also needs more effort to come up with a good suggestion that what anyone here is willing to voluntarily spend. You should consider hiring a paid consultant to help you with your problem. If he is well paid, he might be willing to accept your attitude when he asks for details.

Comment: no offense. I just used capitals to emphasize the main problem that I have not mentioned in the question (I thought that was implicit in my question.) :)

Comment: To take this back to topic and also taking the approach @jarnbjo : You have a legacy web app offering some endpoints. Can you put an nginx (or sth else) in front of it and send all given request to the old app? Once that is done you can put a new spring boot app next to it and migrate endpoint by endpoint. Is that feasible, and if not: why? They would be totally isolated. No compatibility issues I could see.

Comment: the services that I mentioned are the core java (low level) services not HTTP service, they are not exposed directly from the legacy app.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally look to update your Java code to use Spring boot and build new controllers, services and new views using Thymeleaf. It may be a bit of upfront work, however, once you port your App to use Spring Boot, you will be able to manage it better.

Comment: actually there is a plan for this in near future (the code base is really huge, even a custom programming language is defined and implemented inside it!), but the rest API is the priority right now.